# Twilio conference call with nodejs

Tags: node.js, twilio

I want to develop a conference application using [Twilio and Nodejs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install).
In my application first person get a call from twilio number after that first person who received the call need to create a conference and call to another person for joining the same conference room. I have created below code but it is not working.

```
app.post('/callcenter', function(req, res) {
var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
client.makeCall({
     to : config.twilio.to, // Any number Twilio can call
    from : config.twilio.from, // A number you bought from Twilio and can     use for outbound communication
    url : 'http://example.com/createconf' // A URL that produces an XML document (TwiML) which contains instructions for the call

}, function(err, responseData) {
    console.log(responseData.from); // outputs "+14506667788"
    if (err) {
        response.status(500).send(err);
    } else {            
        res.type('text/xml');
        res.send(twiml.toString());
        console.log(twiml.toString());
    }
});
});

app.post('/createconf', function(req, res) {
var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse(); 
console.log('Inside createconf');   
.gather({
    action:'http://exampl.com/enterinconf',
    finishOnKey:'*',
    numDigits:'1',
    timeout:'20'
}, function() {
    this.say('Press 1 for moderator')
        .say('Press 2 for speak');
})
res.type('text/xml');
res.send(twiml.toString());
console.log(twiml.toString());  
});

app.post('/enterinconf', function(req, res) {
var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();


    client.makeCall({
        to : config.twilio.modfwd, // Any number Twilio can call
        from : config.twilio.from, // A number you bought from Twilio and can use for outbound communication
        url : '../conference/moderatorconf.xml' // A URL that produces an XML document (TwiML) which contains instructions for the call

    }, function(err, responseData) {            
        console.log(responseData.from); 
        if (err) {
            response.status(500).send(err);
        } else {                
            res.type('text/xml');
            res.send(twiml.toString());
            console.log(twiml.toString());
        }
    });

});
```

Can somebody help me on this how I can develop a conference call in Nodejs with twilio.

Comment: What's not working about it? How far does the call get?

Comment: It goes into /enterinconf but after that it gives error like 'An application error has occured' also I cannot get the digit pressed by user getting undefined for req.Digits.